# Django - method not allowed error after moving ajax request to different app

Tags: python, django

I have a small form in my django app called ***home*** that I submit through jquery ajax request. Below is the setup that I have

**home urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^submitseries/$', views.submitseries, name='submitseries'),
    url(r'^getstats/$', views.getstats, name='getstats'),
]
```

**home views.py**

```
def submitseries(request,id=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        series_url = request.POST.get("series_url")
    # rest of the processing code that is working fine
```

**application urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(('home.urls','home'),namespace="home")),
    path('series/', include(('series.urls','series'),namespace="series")),
    path('submitseries/', include(('home.urls','submitseries'),namespace="submitseries")),
    path('players/', include(('players.urls','players'),namespace="players")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This setup is working fine but I would like to move this ajax request to a different app in my application that is with name **series**

So I have moved the **submitseries** function to **views.py** of series app modified the

**series urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^$submitseries/', views.submitseries, name='submitseries'),
]
```

*((tried different variations such as series/submitseries/ ))*

modified the **application urls.py** as following

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(('home.urls','home'),namespace="home")),
    path('series/', include(('series.urls','series'),namespace="series")),
    path('submitseries/', include(('series.urls','submitseries'),namespace="submitseries")),
    path('players/', include(('players.urls','players'),namespace="players")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

***rather than pointing it to home.urls I have pointed it to series.url***

But it starts giving **405 Method not allowed error** and it doesn't matter what I try I am not able to solve it.

I have tried giving different variations of path in urls.py of both application and series app. I am just not able to make it work.
The only different in both the setup is that home app is base and the relative path is **"http://localhost:8000/submitseries"**
but when I move it to series app the base url becomes
**"http://localhost:8000/series/submitseries"**

Adding AJAX code as requested

```
//function to submit series url and save to DB
$("#save_series").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    series_url = $("#series_url").val();
    var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    console.log("Series URL " + series_url);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "series/submitseries/",
        data: {"series_url":series_url},
        headers:{
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
        },
        success: function(result){
            message = "Series #" + result["series_id"] + " inserted successfully";
            bootstrap_alert['info'](message);
        },
        error: function(result){
            bootstrap_alert['warning'](result.responseJSON.error_msg);
            
        }
    });//end of ajax submit
    });//end of button click block
```

Comment: have you added the namespace in the url name when using ajax ?

Comment: In the working setup the following url work url : "submitseries/". I have changed the ajax URL to url: "series/submitseries". I assume this covers the namespace part in ajax request.

Comment: show me your ajax  ?

Comment: Is the $ sign in the correct position here? `r'^$submitseries/'`

Comment: I have tried using the absolute path also as mentioned in question in the ajax request but that also gives the same error. So I am assuming that it is the urls.py setting error. I am not able to specify the right value

Comment: added the AJAX portion of the code also to the question

Comment: @BrianD this is working fine for initial setup so I am assuming this is in right position. I am trying to follow online examples for building this so don't have much idea

Comment: try to change this url: "series/submitseries/", to url: "{% url 'submitseries:submitseries' %}".

Comment: It is an external js file so when I use this it doesn't get translated may be I am missing something. but I tried using this action attribute of the form and got following error                   "Reverse for 'submitseries' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['series/submitseries/$submitseries/']"

Comment: why don't you try /submitseries/submitseries/ since your are pointed that way and the urls also.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue thanks to the users pointing out different things in comments.

The first clue was suggestion by *@amadou sow* to use url substituting in JS using following expression

```
{% url 'submitseries:submitseries' %}
```

When I did this in the action attribute of the form then I started getting following error

> "Reverse for 'submitseries' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s)
> tried: ['series/submitseries/$submitseries/']

This made it clear that there is something wrong with endpoint I have provided in the **series urls.py**

After playing with some permutations and combinations what I found is that $ is being evaluated literally rather than a regex symbol in case of subdirectory case and @BrianD comment about the $ being in right place hit the nail in the head.

Finally changing the **series urls.py** to following got the whole thing working

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^submitseries/', views.submitseries, name='submitseries'),
]
```

***P.S. submitseries is without $ in front.***